# angular multiple autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I would like to have an autocomplete on **multiple** values a bit like the one for email addresses in **gmail**.

More precisely, I have a list of emails and I want the user to be able to type the beginning of a mail and then have corresponding mails proposed by the autocomplete. The user must also be able to add addresses that are not set in the list for the autocomplete.

Do you know an Angular way to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Edit :
I'm not sure I'm making myself clear. What I want is an autocomplete where you can choose multiple values. The values selected can either be from an array of data or a free typing (like in gmail when you choose the different recipients)

Answer (score 0):

First you must make a directive to handle auto complete functionality in angular

```
appDirectives.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

and in HTML tag that you need to bind data ['email','email',....] in ui-items="emailsArray" that need to auto complete add attribute 'auto-complete'
example

```
 <input type="text" auto-complete ui-items="emails" />
```